# PhoneGap Cordova Browser based and app

Tags: rest, api, cordova, phonegap

Let say were starting a website from the ground up and want to also create apps.

Could you just create the website with a REST API's and have it work on browser and PhoneGap? Would there be a conflict with Cordova plugins you may use?

So the design is responsive and its all HTML, CSS and Javascript and connects to a REST API (log in, reg, messages, db calls, etc) for the browser website and apps.

This way you can use the same code for everything and can still use some of the great Cordova plugins for the app to make it more flexible.

Would this work?

Answer (score -1):

**I posted this answer else where but I think it is relevant here.**

Unfortunately for your app to pass Apple App store approval it will have to provide some basic functions and display correctly without an internet connection. This means at a minimum, if you plan to generate content on a server you will probably need the Cordova plugin for network information:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/

I would make sure you are familiar with the Apple Human Interface Guidelines:

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/

You will probably also need to bundle any JavaScript. Apple is very picky about apps that download code (this can include JavaScript).

This is a section from the iOS developer Agreement.

> 3.3.2 Except as set forth in the next paragraph, an Application may not download or install executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts, code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and not downloaded. The only exceptions to the foregoing are scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework or JavascriptCore, provided that such scripts and code do not change the primary purpose of the Application by providing features or functionality that are inconsistent with the intended and advertised purpose of the Application as submitted to the App Store.

Another big concern is performance. How will your app handle a poor 3G or even 2G connection? Do you need to cache the responses from the API and only download them if they have changed on the server?

If a user is browsing your website on a browser they know they need an internet connection, if they are using your app they want it to work when online and offline.

**Edit**

Apple commonly uses this reason for rejection for website only apps.

> We found that the experience your app provides is not sufficiently different from a web browsing experience, as it would be by incorporating native iOS functionality.
>
> While your app content may differ from your web site or other existing sites, the experience it provides does not differ significantly from the general experience of using Safari, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

Comment: Interesting.. I have two apps out for iOS and Android that are just a simple WebView to the website.. Also there would be no point for this new app I'm starting on if you don't have an internet connection so offline wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yeah many apps do require that you have an internet connection. I'm just pointing out there is a lot to consider, especially with the Apple App Store review process. Some pure webview apps get through and some don't. I have added a common rejection reason that apple uses for apps that basically​ display a website.

Comment: No problem. Sorry if my answer comes across as a bit negative. Just don't want you put in a lot of effort for an app that may get rejected and you end up having to rework anyway.